# Plot points at 2d on matlab and show the associated image when click on a point

Tags: matlab, figure, user-interaction

I have a collection of images associated to 2d points. I want tot plot those points on a figure and when I click on the points I expect to see the corresponding image on the screen. Suppose I have a matrix `IMAGES` that is nxd where n is number of images and d dimension of each image and I have `Points` matrix that is nx2 which shows the corresponding points as I said.

Can you please any method to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a [callback](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/creating_guis/writing-code-for-callbacks.html) function for `ButtonDownFcn`. It will allow you to get which area has been clicked and execute your code.